# Proof: Two circles have a most 2 intersections

Tags: geometry

I already prooved the statement [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326654/proof-two-non-identical-circles-have-at-most-2-same-points) in general, but know I tried to proove it in an other way:

I put $M_1$ on $(0/0)$ and the x-axis through $M_1$ and $M_2$.

[image]
That simplifies the equatons for circles a lot:
$k_1: x^2+y^2=r_1^2$ and $k_2:(x+a)^2+y^2=r_2^2$ (where $a$ is the distance between $M_1$ and $M_2$). From $k_1$ and $k_2$ I get
$$2ax+a^2-r_1^2+r_2^2=0$$

But now I don't know how to proceed. I think I have to look at different cases: $a=r_1+r_2$, $a>r_1+r_2$ and $0 < a <r_1+r_2$.

Anyone got an idea for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x=...$ and then you have a quadratic in $y$. That has 0,1 or 2 solutions ;)

Comment: Unless they coincide...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice solution, you're almost done.  Regardless of $r_1, r_2, a$, there is a single value for $x$ that will solve the equation.  With that $x$, there will be at most two values for $y$ (you need to prove that a vertical line crosses a circle in at most two places).

Here's how:

> With $x$ fixed, $x^2+y^2=r^2$ has solution $y=\pm \sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, which is 0,1, or 2 solutions depending on whether $r^2-x^2$ is negative, zero, or positive.

Comment: so there is no need for different cases? - Edit: Got it, thanks a lot

Comment: Not with my proof.

Comment: doesn't matter, because I only want to proove "that" the have a most 2 intersections and not "when".